# htaccess force https & www. on domain & http no www on subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, no-www

How do I get in htaccess to force https & www. on domain, & http no www on subdomain?

The following redirects the http://sub.domain.com to https://domain.com

```
# for main domains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


# for sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# for main domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

You need to test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: You! You save the human life from being attacked by the alien! Thank you.